# Random Numbers to select from two tables in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to randomly select a number from two tables in excel, however when I use the RAND() OR RANDBETWEEN() function it does not work . The tables are as follows.

**Table One:**

**Year       Cost**
1    £700,000.00

2    £717,500.00

3    £735,437.50

4    £753,823.44

5    £772,669.02

6    £791,985.75

7    £811,785.39

8    £832,080.03

9    £852,882.03

10   £874,204.08

**Table 2:**

**Year      Cost**

3    £800,000.00

4    £828,000.00

5    £856,980.00

6    £886,974.30

7    £918,018.40

8    £950,149.04

9    £983,404.26

10   £1,017,823.41

11   £1,053,447.23

12   £1,090,317.88

Comment: I just realized that table 2 has no #1 or #2... is that on purpose?

Comment: another thing to look out for is probability.  If you want each number to have the same probability of being picked or if you want equal probability of either table being picked.  This is only an issue if the two tables are of different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

One value of a random cell out of a list in `C1:C10` & `D1:D12`:

```
=IF(RANDBETWEEN(1,22)<=10, 
     "Table1: #" & INDEX($C$1:$C$10,RANDBETWEEN(1,10)),
     "Table2: #" & INDEX($D$1:$DB$12,RANDBETWEEN(1,12)))
```

Or in VBA:

```
MsgBox Range(IIf(Int(Rnd() * 22) + 1 <= 10, "C" & Int(Rnd() * 10) + 1, 
    "D" & Int(Rnd() * 12) + 1)).Value
```

Comment: Your `if`contains an extra `i`? Also your result here would merely return a table number and a random index number, won't actually return the value in the table. For example your formula would return `Table1: #1` instead of `700,000`

Comment: Why do you still have `"Table1: #"&` in your formula? Combining this with `INDEX` doesn't make much sense to me, because now your result would return `Table1: #700000`. The way I interpreted the question, the OP just wants strictly the value in the table and not extra text out front. Just my interpretation though

Comment: So the OP doesn't have to include the table number if the OP chooses not to.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 -- `IIf` = is an "Inline If", and can be used in VBA & Access queries.

Comment: @pnuts - I stand corrected - but on quick check it's close, looks like 40% are referring to it as "[inline](https://www.google.ca/search?num=100&q=iif+%22inline+if%22+OR+%22in-line+if%22+OR+%22in+line+if%22)" (although suddenly the reasoning behind "[immediate](https://www.google.ca/search?num=100&q=iif+%22immediate+if%22+&oq=iif+%22immediate+if%22)" also makes sense)  Thx!

Answer (score 0):

`RAND` and `RANDBETWEEN`  just selects a random *number*, but you still have to use `INDEX` to actually get a value in a range.

For example to randomly select one of the values in cells `A1:A10`, do this:

```
= INDEX(A1:A10,RANDBETWEEN(1,10))
```

More generally, instead of hardcoding `10` into the formula, you can do this:

```
= INDEX(A1:A10,RANDBETWEEN(1,ROWS(A1:A10)))
```